# grep multiple lines with unique count and string

Tags: grep

Sample.csv

```
DSN1,abc,FAILURE,12,24,45
DSN1,def,FAILURE,12,78,65
DSN1,abc,FAILURE,12,24,45
DSN1,abc,FAILURE,12,24,45
DSN1,abc,FAILURE,12,24,45
DSN1,def,FAILURE,12,78,65
DSN1,abc,FAILURE,12,24,45
```

i need the count of failures in the above sample.csv with response as

```
abc 5
def 2
```

but i dont have mention the abc/def in the script. because i have given a sample scenario in my case many of the string like abc are there so i need that string and count with failure.

please suggest me

Thanks in advance

Comment: That sample CSV excerpt has different number of fields on each line; are you sure that's how the file is formatted?

Comment: lack of proper markup

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use the following pipe:

```
<Sample.csv grep '^[^,]*,[^,]*,FAILURE' | cut -d, -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

- `grep` will extract lines with `FAILURE` in the third column
- `cut` will extract the column (separator `,` column number `2`)
- `sort` will sort the extracted column (The same values will be next to each other.)
- `uniq` will remove repeated values, the `-c` option will show counts of every unique value

You can also insert other filters into the pipe as needed. (for example `grep` at the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

Ricky's comment is how I would do it, but if you want a solution specific to grep you could do the following:

```
$ for i in {abc,def}; do echo -n "$i: "; grep -c $i input.txt; done;
```

this will output the expected:

```
abc:5
def:2
```

### Update

If you do not want to include the search keys in the for loop I don't see how to do it simply with just grep.

You could do it with awk though.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}//{a[$2]++}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' test.txt
```

Explanation:

> FS="," -- set record seperator to comma
>
> //  -- match all lines
>
> We create an associate array called 'a'
>
> a[$2]++  --  each pattern matched we take 2nd column and increment count
>
> END { .. }  -- this block is run when done with all matching.
>                      we iterate over all elements printing key and count.

Comment: in for loop i dont want to mention any strings. string should be more then 2 i need dynamic string with the count.

Comment: You should add `FAILURE` as a condition for the count, e.g.: `$3 == "FAILURE" { a[$2]++ } ...`.

Answer (score -2):

please find the same:

```
awk < Sample.txt -F',' '{print $2}' | sort |uniq -c| grep "FAILURE"
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Is this supposed to answer your own question? If so, it would be nice if you could add a short explanation.

Comment: This will not work as the string `FAILURE` does not appear in the second column in your example. (`grep` could be at the pipe beginning though) You should also add some explanation.